# JQM simpledialog2 dynamically change button name in button / input mode

Tags: jquery-mobile, button, dynamic, names, simpledialog

I found this solution to create the values of headerText and buttonPrompt with an js function but is it even possible to use the function to create the button names like 'delete'?

```
$('<div>').simpledialog2({
  mode: 'button',
  headerText: jsFunction(),
  headerClose: true,
  buttons : {
    'Delete': {
      click: function () { 
      ...
```

I need to change the names for localizing my dialogs. Can't use inlining modes because i need click functions. Even in inline mode the inline functions for 'headerText' are not working..

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, think i've found the best solution for this issue..

For the 'buttons' element i've set an id like

```
id: 'my_button_id'
```

then traversed trough the dom to change the button value like this:

```
$("#my_button_id").find('.ui-btn-text').html(some_function);
```

:)